# Getting error while verifying phone number in firebase (angular project)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an angular project, where I am adding MultiFactor Authorisation using firebase authentication, I am trying to verify phone number by firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber function, it should take , phoneInfoOptions and capthaverfier as an argument but I am getting below error ,

error:

> u {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "verifyPhoneNumber failed: First argument "phoneInf…st be a valid string or valid phone info options.", a: null}

My code:

```
var phoneInfoOptions = {
       Hint: this.windowRef.resolver.hints[0],
       session: this.windowRef.resolver.session,
     };
 this.windowRef.verificationId = await phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneInfoOptions,
       appVerifier
     );
```

Comment: please see my suggestion below and lmk if it works!

Answer (score 0):

is there a typo in the phoneInfoOptions field name? from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.multifactorresolver

```
var phoneInfoOptions = {
  multiFactorHint: selectedHint,
  session: resolver.session
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting phone number to string and then pass it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31560148)